# How to implement cell updating using dropdown select in MUI Data Grid?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

For updating a cells in column I use 'type: singleSelect' and 'valueOptions' in Data Grid column definition.

```
  const columns = [
    {
      field: "id",
      headerName: "ID",
      sortable: true,
      maxWidth: 80,
      flex: 1,
    },
    { field: "date", headerName: "Date", flex: 1, maxWidth: 120 },
    {
      field: "source",
      headerName: "Source",
      type: "string",
      sortable: false,
      flex: 1,
      maxWidth: 120
    },
    {
      field: "status",
      headerName: "Status",
      flex: 1,
      editable: true,
      type: "singleSelect",
      valueOptions: [
        { value: 1, label: " " },
        { value: "Confirmed", label: "Confirmed" },
        { value: "Didn't answer", label: "Didn't answer" },
        { value: "Received", label: "Received" },
        { value: "Duplicated", label: "Duplicated" },
        { value: "Complaint", label: "Complaint" },
      ],
```

How to get row id and updated value of cell to send them to the server via axios?

I use React Material UI Community Edition v5.

I tried renderCell to use Select component but it looks ugly

Comment: There are new API for this in latest version https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/editing/#persistence refer this.

Answer (score 1):

hy @centro88 you have

```
      valueOptions: [
    { value: 1, label: " " },
    { value: "Confirmed", label: "Confirmed" },
    { value: "Didn't answer", label: "Didn't answer" },
    { value: "Received", label: "Received" },
    { value: "Duplicated", label: "Duplicated" },
    { value: "Complaint", label: "Complaint" },
  ],
```

its wroking r not.. we have diff label and value, can we do this way

Answer (score 0):

The Data Grid has a prop called 'onCellEditCommit'.  You can stick your axios function in there, it is passed the updated row data from the cell that was edited.

```
const sendToServer = async(data) => {
    // send to server logic
}
```

```
<DataGrid
    onCellEditCommit={sendToServer}
    ...
/>
```

From MUI DataGrid API: [https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/data-grid/#props:~:text=onCellEditCommit,for%20this%20callback](https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/data-grid/#props:%7E:text=onCellEditCommit,for%20this%20callback).